# End of Array Function Not Working Correctly in Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, while-loop

I have written a custom function in google apps script that takes the values from a spreadsheet in the form of a 2D array, and loops through them checking if the values are undefined or an empty string. However, I am getting that the first value is equal to an empty string, when it is certainly not. I am also getting that the value is NOT equal to an empty string, which doesn't make any sense at all. The value of the first

Here is my code:

```
function lastColumnWithValue(row, cells) {

  var i = 0;
//cells[row][i] = 0 to start with
//not getting into while loop
  Logger.log(cells[row][i]);
  Logger.log(cells[row][i] === "");
  Logger.log(cells[row][i] != undefined && cells[row][i] != "")
  Logger.log(cells[row][i] != undefined);
  Logger.log(cells[row][i] != "")//returns false
  Logger.log(cells[row][i] === "")//returns false

  while (cells[row][i] != undefined && cells[row][i] != "") {

   i++; 



  }
    Logger.log("i - 1: " + (i - 1))
  return i - 1;




}
```

Comment: How are you getting the `cells` argument value? I tested by placing  `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]; var cells = sheet.getRange("A1:F5").getValues(); var row = 1` within the function and can not reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar sort of thing and it works just fine.  I think part of the problem is this: `while (cells[row][i] != undefined && cells[row][i] != "")` should be something like this: `while (cells[row][i] != 'undefined' && cells[row][i] != "")` for the last part I just did this `!row[j] in my code`

The Code:

```
function testingMyData() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rg=sh.getDataRange();
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    if(!containsNulls(vA))
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No nulls');
    }
    else
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Nulls');
    }

}

function containsNulls(A)
{
  for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++)
  {
      var row=A[i];
      for(var j=0;j<row.length;j++)
      {
        if(!row[j] && typeof(row[j])!='undefined')
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
  }
  return false;
}
```

My Spreadsheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your function name is

> lastColumnWithValue

Why don't you use the built in last column function?

> getLastColumn

**Example**

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()

Comment: Idk about them, but range.getLastColumn() doesn't work for me, just gives me the last column of the range even tho the last 10 columns are blank...